# Charting Sales Order stats

Tags: vb.net, charts, datatable

I have a datatable that has the columns: **Order Number**, a count of **Lines**, and a sum of **Units**.  I want to end up with charts shown here.  [3 charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDFSD.png) Each shows a column for 1 through 20 and then >20

The problem is looping through the datatable takes over 1.5 minutes.

```
        Dim XAxis(21) As String
        Dim LinesPO(21) As Integer 'Lines per Order
        Dim UnitsPO(21) As Integer 'Units Per Order
        Dim UnitsPL(21) As Integer 'Units Per Line

        For Each Dr As DataRow In LivesqlDt2.Rows
            For i = 0 To 21
                If i < 21 Then
                    XAxis(i) = i.ToString
                    If Dr.Item("Lines") = i Then LinesPO(i) += 1
                    If Dr.Item("Units") = i Then UnitsPO(i) += 1
                    If Math.Round(Dr.Item("Units") / Dr.Item("Lines"), 0) = i Then UnitsPL(i) += 1
                Else
                    XAxis(i) = ">20"
                    If Dr.Item("Lines") >= i Then LinesPO(i) += 1
                    If Dr.Item("Units") >= i Then UnitsPO(i) += 1
                    If Math.Round(Dr.Item("Units") / Dr.Item("Lines"), 0) >= i Then UnitsPL(i) += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

I'm looking for any good ideas to speed this up, because the salesman wants to be able to run this in front of their customer.

Comment: How are you getting the data? It's usually a lot faster to do the processing at that point rather than in code looping through various ````DataRow```` items and using implicit casting for math equations.

Comment: I am using a sql query that counts the Lines and sums the Units for each order.  I use the data to slice and dice it a few ways, this is just the part that gets bogged down.

Comment: Well, for each row you should cast your Lines/Total fields to a Decimal or Integer once, and then use that variable in each equation instead of using the DataRow.Item object each time.  But honestly, I would think about having your SQL query return those values instead of trying to do it in code (GROUP BYs, SUM(), MAX(), etc... )